# Help me to Get this code work

Tags: c#

What is wrong with this code? i can get correct value? DrvUsg always getting zero. please help me to get work this code.

```
    Computer cmp = new Computer();
    string SysDrv = System.Environment.SystemDirectory.Substring(0, 2);
    UInt64 TotalDrv = Convert.ToUInt64(cmp.FileSystem.GetDriveInfo(SysDrv).TotalSize / 1024 / 1024);
    UInt64 FreeDrv = Convert.ToUInt64(cmp.FileSystem.GetDriveInfo(SysDrv).AvailableFreeSpace / 1024 / 1024);
    UInt64 UsedDrv = (TotalDrv - FreeDrv);
    UInt64 DrvUsg = Convert.ToUInt64((UsedDrv / TotalDrv) * 100);
    TrkDrvUsg.Value = (int)DrvUsg;
    LblDrvUsg.Text = (String.Format("System drive usage: {0}%", DrvUsg));
```

Comment: This reeks of a very putrid stench of integer division.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
UInt64 DrvUsg = Convert.ToUInt64((UsedDrv / TotalDrv) * 100);
```

This will work:

```
UInt64 DrvUsg = Convert.ToUInt64(100 * UsedDrv / TotalDrv);
```

You were doing an integer division which will always round down, since `TotalDrv` is larger than `UsedDrv` the result was always zero.